# How do i copy the columns from a table and insert it into another table with a sequenced column?(PostgreSQ

Tags: database, postgresql, function

I have a table called test_pois and i want to copy the columns code and fclass to the columns on the table test_fclass.

But the problem is, that the table test_fclass has a column named fid, which is a sequenced column. So i want the copied columns just for once. I'm using PostgreSQL. How could i realize it ? I thought of writing a function , but maybe there is an easier way.

In the end , i want to create a foreign key on the table test_pois which reduces 2 columns into 1 with an id.

Maybe you would say, make it by writing some inserts, but there is a lot of data in it.

[image: Columns of test_pois]

[image: Columns of test_fclass]

I used the following insert into statement to copy the data from the test_pois table :

```
insert into test_fclass (fcode, fclass) select code, fclass from test_pois;
```

The output:

[image]

As you can see the ids 4-7 are assigned for code 2907. But I want a uniqe id for code 2907.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add the expected output based on your sample data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Why is a "sequenced" column a problem?  And, does that mean a `serial` column?

Comment: What about a simple `insert into test_fclass (code, fclass) select code, fclass from test_pois;`

Comment: Yes it's a serial column. The problem is that there is more than one row with the same fclass and fcode  But i want some unique data on my table test_fclass.

Comment: i tried the insert into statement but i have for example for  code 2907 more than one id, but i want just one specific id for a specific code, so what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I made it with a plpgsql function.

```
    CREATE or replace FUNCTION populate() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    anzahl integer;
    zahl integer;
    zahl2 integer;
    text varchar(20);
    count integer;
    varcode smallint;
    var integer;
    varclass character varying(20);
    curse CURSOR FOR SELECT fcode FROM fclass;

    poiscurse cursor for select code from test_pois;
BEGIN

var := 0;
anzahl:= 0;
zahl := 0;
for v_anzahl in poiscurse
loop

var := var +1;
--raise notice '%',var;
text := v_anzahl::text;
SELECT substring(text FROM '[0-9]+') into zahl;
select code,fclass into varcode,varclass
from test_pois
where code = zahl;
if var = 1 then
insert into fclass (fcode, fclass) values (varcode,varclass);
raise notice '% and % inserted',varcode,varclass;
end if;
anzahl := 0;
for v_zahl in curse
loop
text := v_zahl::text;
SELECT substring(text FROM '[0-9]+') into zahl2;
if zahl = zahl2 then
anzahl := anzahl +1;
exit;
end if;
end loop;
if anzahl = 0 then
insert into fclass (fcode, fclass) values (varcode,varclass);
raise notice '% und % eingefügt',varcode,varclass;
end if;
end loop;
end;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

And the output:

[image]

Thanks for the answers by the way.